# Bash script to run programs with parameters not working

Tags: linux, bash

Hello and thanks for reading.
I am a beginner when it comes to using linux so this question might seem dull to most of you, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere to it.
I'm trying to run 6 programs using a bash script, and they each require a config file to be specified as a parameter.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
./shout/sc_serv "sc_serv.conf" &
./rshout/sc_serv "sc_serv.conf" &
./dshout/sc_serv "sc_serv.conf" &
./trans/sc_trans "sc_trans_dj.conf" &
./rtrans/sc_trans "sc_trans_dj.conf" &
./dtrans/sc_trans "sc_trans_dj.conf" &
```

These give the following error:

```
msg:[CONFIG] Could not find `sc_trans_dj.conf' - will now prompt for a config file to load
WARN [CONFIG] Could not find `sc_serv.conf' - looking for config file to load...
```

Also tried adding the same path to the configs,

```
#!/bin/bash
./shout/sc_serv "/shout/sc_serv.conf" &
./rshout/sc_serv "/rshout/sc_serv.conf" &
./dshout/sc_serv "/dshout/sc_serv.conf" &
./trans/sc_trans "/trans/sc_trans_dj.conf" &
./rtrans/sc_trans "/rtrans/sc_trans_dj.conf" &
./dtrans/sc_trans "/dtrans/sc_trans_dj.conf" &
```

But then it gives the same error,

```
2014-05-31 12:44:54     WARN    [CONFIG] Could not find `/dshout/sc_serv.conf' - looking for config file to load...
```

Paths are like this:

```
/home/user/script
/home/user/shout/sc_serv
/home/user/shout/sc_serv.conf
```

and so on.

Please keep in mind, when answering, that I am looking for the simplest solution as I've seen numerous threads and couldn't understand anything. I just need it to work for this one case and not a script that will universally work for everything, so no path getting and so on, if I need the full path, that's fine also

Edit:: thank you for editing my post, I am new here and don't know how to properly indent things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in the home directory I think you mean:

```
#!/bin/bash
./shout/sc_serv "./shout/sc_serv.conf" &
...
```

Note the added . at the beginning.

Another way is to give absolute forms instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
./shout/sc_serv "/home/user/shout/sc_serv.conf" &
...
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the quick answer. I tried doing it like you said but it still gives the same error. This is what I've tried: ./shout/sc_serv "/home/user/shout/sc_serv.conf" &

Comment: Ignore my last comment. So it's running now, with the dots added, but I still have an issue. The programs itself now basically run from the directory the bash is in, and so nothing works because there are several hardcoded paths in the configs. Can I somehow run the programs from the script so they run from their own folders?

Comment: Try something like `( cd /home/user/shout; exec ./sc_serv sc_serv.conf; ) &`. Of course `cd /home/user/shout` can be `cd ./shout` but that would need that you always run the caller script in `/home/user`.

Comment: this is how I would usually do it: go to the shout folder, and type ./sc_serv sc_serv.conf . The program would start and use files from it's own "shout" directory without the full path. For example, the "trans" folder containing "sc_trans", after being run, will look for a "playlist" folder in the folder it was run from, and run a playlist.pls file from inside it. Because of how it's running now, it's not executing the playlist file because it can't find it. Edit:: trying what you said now

Comment: See my latest reply for that. Also if `sc_serv` is ran by a same kind of shell (e.g. `bash`), then instead of using `exec` you could just "`source`" the file with `. ./sc_serv sc_serv.conf`. It's less safe since you get to use the unexported variables of the calling script but perhaps your scripts need not to be that conservative.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working perfectly now with full paths using ( cd /home/user/shout; exec ./sc_serv sc_serv.conf; ) &

Comment: Sure no prob. Welcome.